# geth javascript console

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, nodejs

when I am trying to run this command on geth console.it give an error.how to run this command on geth console.

run geth with this commnad

```
 geth --port 5000 --networkid 58342  --datadir="" --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --testnet
```

> web3.eth.accounts.create();
>   TypeError: 'create' is not a function
>       at :1:1

Comment: There is no create function for `eth` ,  do you want to create a account?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to load [personal](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal) library `--rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal"` and i don't thin using `--datadir=""`  is a good idea.

```
 geth --port 5000 --networkid 58342   --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal" --testnet
```

Answer (score 1):

## Try to use personal.newAccount('passphrase')

## and use rpcapi="eth,personal,miner,web3"

(1) First start your geth
geth --port 5000 --networkid 58342  --datadir="" --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,personal,net,web3" --testnet

(2) Now Open Ethereum's Javascript console
geth attach ipc

(3) Create new address
personal.newAccount('passphrase')

Answer (score 0):

There are atleast 3 methods to create account:

#### method 1: with geth directly ( without geth javascript console )

```
geth --datadir node1/ account new --password "your password"
```

#### method 2: for javascript console.

attach to node with

```
geth attach node1/geth.ipc
```

then at console

```
personal.newAccount('your password')
```

#### method 3: with web3.js (also .py, .go, .dart etc. are available )

```
const Web3=require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8546"); // rpc: node 1

accountDetails= web3.eth.accounts.create() // or web3.eth.accounts.create('password') or web3.eth.accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32))

console.log(accountDetails);
```

all above 3 methods works perfectly with blockchain made with geth (go-ethereum ).